# Undefined validation function "xxx" on field

Tags: go, go-gin

When I just upgraded `Gin` from v1.4.0 to v1.5.0, I used the 'BindJSON' function as usual,
and threw this error.

```sh
2019/11/29 11:44:13 [Recovery] 2019/11/29 - 11:44:13 panic recovered:
Undefined validation function 'exists' on field 'FirstName'
...
```

Here's my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type User struct {
    FirstName *string `json:"fn" binding:"exists"` 
}

    
func main(){
    router := gin.Default()
    router.POST("/register", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var user User
        if err := c.BindJSON(&user); err != nil {
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
                    "error": "first name cannot be empty",
                   })
            return
        }
    })

    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Gin.v1.4.0 use validator.v8 for validation and gin.v1.5.0 use validator.v9,  and  validator removes `exists` tag  from v8 to v9.

So you can define the struct like this:

```golang
type User struct {
// FirstName *string `json:"fn" binding:"exists"`
FirstName *string `json:"fn" binding:"required"`
}
```

Likewise, if you use the "required" tag and get this error, check your `go.mod` file  and try upgrading "github.com/go-playground/validator/v8" to v9 or v10.